# AJAX fails only inside JQuery dialog box

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-dialog

**How it works**

1. I have a page called `displayRecord.php` which is loaded inside a
   JQuery dialog box. The dialog box is created inside `editTicket.php`
2. Basically the displayRecord.php allows a user to add a username &
   ref id and via AJAX `$.post` it updates the DB and retrieves the
   number of record in the respective table.
3. The retrieve counter step is also meant to occur on page load so
   that not only is it displayed when the user adds the username &
   password but when the page loads for the first time.

**What's failing to work**

Step 3 above fails when the displayRecord.php page is inside the JQuery dialog (or atleast thats what I've discovered). If I go to the URL it displays the counter on load. Step 2 still works inside the dialog.

**JQuery dialog box call from editTicket.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dlg = '';
$(document).ready(function() { 

     dlg=$('#ticketDetails').dialog({
        title: 'TICKET DETAILS',
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        show:'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { dlg.dialog("close"); } },
        close: function(e, i) { dlg.hide(); },
        width: 1300   
     });


    $('a.view').click(

        function(e) 
            {    
                dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
                dlg.dialog('open');

            });

        });
});
```

**calling the showCount function on load in displayRecord.php:**

```
<?php if (@$data['escalate'] == "No"){ ?>
        <body onLoad="showCount()">
<?php } else{ ?>
        <body>
    <?php } ?>
```

**showCount function:**

```
function showCount(){

    var ticket_id = <?php echo $data['id']; ?>

    $.post('escalationCount.php',{post_ticket_id:ticket_id}, 
    function(data) {
    $('#escalationCount').html(data);
    });
}
```

As state before the on page load function doesn't appear to be firing inside the JQuery dialog box.

I'm struggling at this point to identify the source of the problem. Some help please, Thanks.

Comment: The `onload` function only runs when the page is loaded. Displaying a dialog doesn't reload the page. BTW, it should be `onload=`, not `onLoad=`.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for that. I'm fairly new to Javascript/JQuery. Would you have any suggestions on how to enable the functionality i'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and I'm not sure I do):

```
$('a.view').click(

    function(e) 
        {    
            dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
                <?php if (@$data['escalate'] == "No") { echo 'showCount();' } ?>
                dlg.dialog('open');

        });

    });
```

This will update the counter when the dialog is opened.

Comment: That makes sense however its not gonna work 'as is' since my `editTicket.php` file does not know about $data['escalate']. I shall give it a go and come back, thanks!

Comment: I assumed that was where the above `<body onLoad="showCount()">` was. Your question doesn't clearly delineate what was in what file.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to keep the information load to minimal so kinda missed out on adding that. `$data['escalate']` is actually in `displayRecord.php` (added).